# Print statement gives not callable error

Tags: python, callable

```
print = ('Tell me about your pet. ')
about_pet = input()

if 'dog'.lower() in about_pet == True :
    print('ah, a dog')
if 'cat'.lower() in about_pet == True :
    print ('ooh, a kitty')

print ('Thanks for the story')
```

when I run this code I get an error:

str object is not callable

What causes this?

Comment: Do you need the '=' after the first print?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the error.

Answer (score 3):

`print = ('Tell me about your pet. ')` overwrites the function `print` as a string. It's not longer a function after that, so any time you try to call it as a function later, you're going to get errors.

Get rid of the `=` so you aren't changing what `print` is.